# Beginning Django: Access elements via foreign key

Tags: python, django

I recently started with using django and have been stuck for a while now.
I have created three models:

```
class Depot(models.Model):
    depot_name = models.CharField(max_length = 200)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.depot_name

class Stock(models.Model):
    stock_key = models.CharField(max_length = 200)
    company_name = models.CharField(max_length = 200)
    price = models.FloatField()
    def __str__(self):
        return self.company_name
    def get_price(self):
        return self.price

class Asset(models.Model):
    depot = models.ForeignKey(Depot, on_delete= models.CASCADE)
    stock = models.ForeignKey(Stock, on_delete= models.CASCADE, related_name="testName")
    number_of_stocks = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    def value(self):
        p = self.testName.price
        return p*self.number_of_stocks
    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.stock)+" "+str(self.number_of_stocks)+" "+str(self.value())
```

Basically to calculate the value of an asset I need the price of its stock. I have not found anything how to access the data of the class stock via the ForeignKey. Maybe it is to trivial. I would really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be trivial...

```
def value(self):
    p = self.stock.price
    return p*self.number_of_stocks
```

the `related_name` on a foreign key is for accessing the other end of the relationship, ie.

```
class Stock(...):
    ...
    def some_method(self):
        assets = self.testName.all()
```

if you had not defined the `related_name="testName"` the last line of the above would need to be

```
assets = self.asset_set.all()
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for your quick answer. Unfortunately it did not help me to solve my problem. Your suggestion helps me to access the data of the Asset model from a method of the stock class. But I want to do it the other way round. I have a method in the Asset class, which needs data from the stock class. What do I have to do different then or is the use of the foreignKeys wrong in this case?

Comment: The first example is the `value` method from your `Asset` class and does what you need. Notice the second line says `self.stock.price` instead of your `self.testName.price`. If that doesn't help I'll need the full traceback.

Comment: Yes, now it works. I was sure that I tried something like that. Now it works. Thanks a lot for your clarifications.